# Is it possible to inverse polymorphic association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I have four models : User, Product, Ownership, and Location. Product belongs to User through Ownership and User has many Products through Ownership.
When a User create a Product, I want that if the User has a Location, the Product is linked to the same Location. So here is my question :

Can we transform this :

```rb
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :localizable, polymorphic: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :location, as: :localizable
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :location, as: :localizable
end
```

into this :

```rb
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :localizables, polymorphic: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location, as: :localizable
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location, as: :localizable
end
```

Comment: You cannot do it this way: the query can just fetch one model at a time.

Comment: Then when a User create a Product, I must duplicate the User's Location to associate it with the Product ?

Comment: there is few added value to extract location from a model, it's hell for queries etc...

Comment: is there a relation between User and Product? When User creates a product how are they related, does product belong to user?

Comment: Product belongs to User through Ownership.

Answer (score 1):

How about delegating `product.location` to `product.owner.location`.

This can be done in the Product class as follows (change identifier for the owner/user relation as needed):

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  delegate :location, to: :owner
end
```

If you call `product.location`, the location of the *owner* will be returned.

Comment: OK, but when the location of the product is not the same as those of the owner ?